# TikZ in standalone not centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a diagram with the code below. When I compile this code, I have an extra empty space on the left side. Why does that happen and what can I do to fix it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{b} = [rectangle, draw, node distance=2.6cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=8em, minimum width=6em, thick, font=\small, fill=black!10]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\node [b] (1) {block 1 \\ block 1};
\node [b, right of=1] (2) {block 2 \\ block 2};
\node [b, right of=2] (3) {block 3 \\ block 3};
\node [b, right of=3] (4) {block 4 \\ block 4};
\node [b, right of=4] (5) {block 5 \\ block 5};


\node [b, below = 2mm of 1] (6) {block 6 \\ block 6};
\node [b, below = 2mm of 2] (7) {block 7 \\ block 7};
\node [b, right of=7] (8) {block 8 \\ block 8};
\node [b, right of=8] (9) {block 9 \\ block 9};

\draw[-, thick] (1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5);
\draw[-, thick] (2)--(7)--(8)--(9)--(4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the end of line after the `\tikzstyle` declaration. Move it before `\begin{document}`.

By the way, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated and I changed it to the currently preferred format.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  b/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    node distance=2.6cm,
    text width=6em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=8em,
    minimum width=6em,
    thick,
    font=\small,
    fill=black!10,
  },
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\node [b] (1) {block 1 \\ block 1};
\node [b, right of=1] (2) {block 2 \\ block 2};
\node [b, right of=2] (3) {block 3 \\ block 3};
\node [b, right of=3] (4) {block 4 \\ block 4};
\node [b, right of=4] (5) {block 5 \\ block 5};


\node [b, below = 2mm of 1] (6) {block 6 \\ block 6};
\node [b, below = 2mm of 2] (7) {block 7 \\ block 7};
\node [b, right of=7] (8) {block 8 \\ block 8};
\node [b, right of=8] (9) {block 9 \\ block 9};

\draw[-, thick] (1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5);
\draw[-, thick] (2)--(7)--(8)--(9)--(4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, so that's the explanation. An easier fix if he really needs the local definition is to add a `%` after the `]` then.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

and it will delete the trailing space.

[image]

Comment: You should _always_ use this optional arguments when using tikz code!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to get rid of the newlines (and the deprecated `\tikzstyle`) which cause this problem is moving the tikz style into the optional argument of `\begin{tikzpicture}`:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        auto,
        b/.style={rectangle, draw, node distance=2.6cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=8em, minimum width=6em, thick, font=\small, fill=black!10},
    ]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot change the preamble for any reason, the newlines can be ignored by ending each line between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}` with a comment:

```
\begin{document}%
%
\tikzstyle{b} = [rectangle, draw, node distance=2.6cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=8em, minimum width=6em, thick, font=\small, fill=black!10]%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]\begin{document}%
...
```